# Counting how many lines continue to next line in bash?

Tags: linux, bash

how to find out how many lines continue to next line in bash?
I have an bash script and I need to count how many lines continue to next line.

Comment: Have you defined "continue to the next line" yet?

Comment: All the lines except the last one?

Comment: It is equal to the total number of lines minus the _number of lines that don't continue to next line_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we define a line that "continues to next line in bash" as a line that ends in backslash, the the number of lines that continue to the next one can be found from:

```
grep  '\\$' file1 | wc -l
```

`grep` selects the lines ending in a backslash and `wc-l` counts them.

The equivalent solution using `sed` looks like:

```
sed -n '/\\$/p' file1 | wc -l
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works fine. My self was trying with grep -R "\\$" <mysourcedir>/* | wc -l but it doesn't work.

Comment: @abadjm With the regex expression in double-quotes, `bash` processes it first, removing one of the blackslashes, before passing it on to `grep`.  The use of single-quotes, as in the answer here, prevents that.